# Automatically TeX-fold paragraph after "}" + SPC

Tags: auctex, code-folding, smartparens

I have defined the following `smartparens` pair:

```
    (sp-pair  "\\textit\{" "\}"
              :trigger "ital "
              :wrap "C-S-k")
```

Now, when I write "ital" and press space, emacs prints `\textit{|}`, where `|` is the cursor. That is great and works exactly the way I want it.

Now, I want AUCTeX to autofold this command so I only see the text within the brackets in italics.  I use this script from https://www.flannaghan.com/2013/01/11/tex-fold-mode:

```
    (add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 
  (lambda () 
    (TeX-fold-mode 1)
    (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'TeX-fold-buffer t t)
    (add-hook 'after-change-functions 
          (lambda (start end oldlen) 
            (when (= (- end start) 1)
              (let ((char-point                                 ;set char-point to single character
                             (buffer-substring-no-properties 
                              start end)))
               (when (or (string= char-point "}")               ; once "}"
                     (string= char-point "$"))                  ; or "$" is typed,
                (TeX-fold-paragraph)))))                        ; fold the paragraph
           t t)))
```

And now comes the problem: Whenever I write "ital" + Space, `\textit{}` is folded into three blue dots before I can insert any text and the cursor is placed next to these dots. This is due to the nature of the function: It folds as soon as "}" is typed. Of course, I could simply unfold the function with my cursor, but this is not the way TeX-fold is supposed to work.

So what I want is AUCTeX to fold once I hit space after "}". This way, I can type "ital" + space, write the text to be italicized, tab out of the parentheses, hit space again and the italicized text is shown.

I have tried to modify the function such that char-point is a two-character string by `(= (- end start) 2)` and `string= char-point "}("SPC")"`, but that did not work. I'm a beginner with emacs and elisp and afraid that my knowledge ends here. Can anyone of you help me out?